# Trouble passing the data from multiple selected tableview cells initially populated from Realm into another VC tableview. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have been at this for a few days now, what I am trying to do is to be able to select 5 cells (previous populated by a realm database). Any help on this would be really appreciated.
Thanks Mark

The following is my current code as is relates to the Segue to pass the data. I think I have edited the code down to the key elements. Let me know if you need any other information.

Edits Made - based on the suggestion made below. I took a step back and approached the problem differently, and developed a solution. I have updated the code below to reflect my working solution. Hope this helps someone else in the future. Cheers Mark

**Primary VC**

```
  import UIKit
     import RealmSwift

class ExercisesSelectionTimed: UITableViewController{
    
     var realm = try! Realm()
     var exercises : Results<ExercisesModel>?

     @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //populates the Realm Data with the default list
            exercises = realm.objects(ExercisesModel.self)
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return exercises?.count ?? 0
            }
     
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExercisesAddedTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ExercisesAddedTableViewCell
        // get the specific exercise in the array
        let exercise = exercises?[indexPath.row]
            cell.exercisenameLabel.text = exercise?.name
            cell.equipmentnameLabel.text = exercise?.equipment
        return cell
        }
     
      private func registerTableViewCells() {
        let textFieldCell = UINib(nibName: "ExercisesAddedTableViewCell",bundle: nil)
        self.tableview.register(textFieldCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "ExercisesAddedTableViewCell")
            }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        switch (timerSelected) {
            case "FGB":
                //User needs to select 5 exercises to populate the FGB timer on the next VC
                    if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
                        //lets the user select 5 cells
                        if selectedRows.count == 5 {
                            performSegue(withIdentifier: K.FGB, sender: self)
                            }
                     }
            default : print ("error")
            }
        }
    
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        switch (timerSelected) {
            case "FGB":
                if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
                    let selected = selectedRows.map{exercises?[$0.row]}
                    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! FBGTimerVCTable
                    
                    destinationVC.selectedExercise = selected 
           }
           default : print ("error")
    }
}


}//last bracket in Class
```

**The target for the data**

```
  import UIKit
    import RealmSwift

class FBGTimerVCTable: HeartRateMonitorBrain{
        
    var realm = try! Realm()
    var selectedExercise = [ExercisesModel?]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        }
    }//last bracket in Class

extension FBGTimerVCTable: UITableViewDataSource{

//setup tableview
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
        }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExercisesAddedTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ExercisesAddedTableViewCell
    //get the specific 5 exercises selected in the ExercisesSelectionTimed VC
    cell.exercisenameLabel.text = selectedExercise[indexPath.row]?.name
    cell.equipmentnameLabel.text = selectedExercise[indexPath.row]?.equipment
    return cell
        }
private func registerTableViewCells() {
    let textFieldCell = UINib(nibName: "ExercisesAddedTableViewCell",bundle: nil)
    self.tableview.register(textFieldCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "ExercisesAddedTableViewCell")
        }
}//last bracket in Class Extension
```

**Realm**

```
 import RealmSwift

class ExercisesModel : Object {
         @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
         @objc dynamic var equipment : String = ""
         }
```

Comment: Why don’t you make the property in the other VC into an array? `var selectedExercises : [ExercisesModel]`

Comment: I did try that but I continue to receive the same type of error and by changing the type I am no longer able to access the properties ie exercise.name & exercise .equipment

Comment: Well what do you want to start with, should the user be able to select one or multiple rows? This is the first thing you need to decide and then adjust your code accordingly

Comment: thanks @JoakimDanielson, I took a step back and approached the problem differently based on  your comments. I have edited the original post to show the working code solution. everything now works as intended. cheers Mark

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for posting the question. But. While adding additional content to a question is good, totally editing it to make it an answer it bad! It looses all context of what the issue initially was making it somewhat useless to future readers. It's better to answer your own question with the updated code so users will understand the initial issue and then the resolution. As is, we have no idea what caused the issue in the first place.

Comment: @jay Thanks for the feedback and helping me understand best way to edit, for future questions. Cheers